# Flutter ListView touch listener

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I find that the user has lifted his finger off the screen after scrolling the `ListView`. I want to use `ScrollController.jumpTo(...)` when this event happens. And I couldn't find any callback like this.

PS: I tried using `GestureDetector` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

I found that.

```
ScrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(() {// scrolling stopped});
```

If anyone knows a better solution please write it down. I am more than happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `ListView` in `NotificationListener` and listens for `UserScrollNotification`.

```
NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.idle) {
      print("Scrolling stopped");
    }
  },
  child: ListView.builder(...),
),
```